# Is there a better way to write conditional structures with Elixir since version1.3

Tags: elixir

Elixir 1.3 introduces the deprecation of imperative assignments, meaning that a code block similar to:

```
def modify(state) do
  if some_condition do
    state = modify_my_state(state)
  end

  # some other stuff may happen now here

  state
end
```

Will produce a warning at compile since `state` is out of scope. This is understandable. But the suggested solution results in this:

```
def modify(state) do
  state = if some_condition do
    modify_my_state(state)
  else 
    state
  end

  # some other stuff may happen now here

  state
end
```

I find it a bit redundant. Is there any other way to make this more clean? Note that the following solution breaks the initial design:

```
def modify(state) do
  state = if some_condition do
    modify_my_state(state)
  end

  # some other stuff may happen now here

  state
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the redundancy is needed to prevent `state` from being out of scope.

Making it "cleaner" is just a matter of coding preferences. Here are 2 solutions that come to mind:

1. **Ternary expression**

`state = if some_condition, do: modify_my_state(state), else: state`

2. **Pattern matching of the modifying function:**

`state = modify_my_state(state, some_condition)`

and then pattern match against `modify_my_state/2`:

```
defp modify_my_state(state, true), do: modify_my_state(state)
defp modify_my_state(state, false), do: state
```